# What does score tell me in getnetworkinfo?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cli, p2p

Using `bitcoin-cli getnetworkinfo`;

Or, going into Help>Debug>Console in bitcoin-qt and typing `getnetworkinfo`;

What does localaddresses:score tell me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's about the network reliability to other nodes, score keeps increasing the longer your node is reachable.